# While creating a dynamic module in Nest.js should i use registerAsync or forRootAsync?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

While creating a [dynamic module](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#dynamic-modules) some of the nestjs modules are using **registerAsync()** some use **forRootAsync()**. which is the recommended method or is there any difference between these two?

```
PassportModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useExisting: PassportConfigService,
}),

TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useExisting: TypeormConfigService,
}),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66371656/difference-forroot-and-forfeature-nest-js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The names are just conventions and do not influence your application's behavior. Nevertheless, it is important to choose a name that properly fits your use case. I would consider the following criteria:

If your module has to be imported differently in root/child modules, then stick with `forRoot`/`forChild`.

Otherwise, use a name that describes your use case. Why do you need a *dynamic* import in the first place and what does it do? For instance: 
`MyDatabaseModule.populate(data)` vs. `MyDatabaseModule.createConnection(configuration)`

Not all dynamic modules are actually asynchronous. So only use the postfix `async` if your import actually is (or can be) asynchronous. This also gives you the opportunity to offer both a synchronous and an asynchronous variant of the import.