# Difference forRoot and forFeature [Nest JS]

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to understand the difference between forRoot and forFeature in nest js dynamic modules.

I also would like to understand this difference in the case of the TypeOrm dynamic module used with nestjs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally speaking, as this does not always hold true, `forRoot`/`register` is a way to provide the configuration the module is going to use whereas `forFeature` is away to create a dynamic provider that has it's own injection token.

In the case of the `TypeOrmModule` as you mentioned, `forRoot()` sets up the connection information that Nest makes use of, and Nest creates the injection token for the `connection` that is created. For `forFeature`, Nest takes that connection injection token under the hood and creates the injection token and custom provider for the repositories that were passed n. The token usually looks like `<EntityName>Repository`, and uses a factory under the hood to inject the connection and get the repository out from the TypeORM system so it can be injected into your regular services.

Comment: Why doesn't the forRoot method here: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/7.0.0/lib/typeorm.module.ts return an object with an export member?

Comment: @Platus, it does.

What about the explanation here that kind of conflicts or expands upon what you said?
https://gist.github.com/darwinsubramaniam/f0ee125e0cee21ba787cc93c60272c79

Answer (score 11):

From Nest.js Discord,

- `forRoot` / `forRootAsync`: configure a module **one time**. This is either for a global service, or a re-used configuration internally
- `forFeature` / `forFeatureAsync`: make use of the configuration from forRoot/forRootAsync **for a specific provider**. This usually creates an injection token.
- `register` / `registerAsync`: a module that can be registered **multiple times** with different configurations each time.

Answer (score 3):

The official explanation (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#community-guidelines) is also helpful.

Use `forRoot` if you are expecting to configure a dynamic module once and reuse that configuration in multiple places.

Use `forFeature` to use the configuration of a dynamic module's forRoot but need to modify some configuration specifics in the calling module.